# setcontentview and findViewById is not able to find xml and ID in layout

Tags: android-layout

We are trying to compile open source project in eclipse. (The project, source code etc are uploaded).
But getting error in line 
  setContentView(R.layout.private_chat);

private_chat is giving error as: 
" private_chat cannot be resolved or is not a field
    - Line breakpoint:PrivateChat [line: 435] - onCreate"

though private_chat.xml file is present in the resource directory.
Can anyone help me how to debug issue further or why it is not recognizing the xml file though it is present in the project.

Thanks in advance!!!,

Regards,
Sandeep

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the line:

```
import android.R;
```

And replace it with your project's R file.

After deleting android.R, pressing CTRL+Shift O should pop up a dialog with two options in it.

Comment: Thanks its working.but in some cases pressing CTRL+SHIFT O it is showing 3 options                                                 1.import 'R'(android) 2.import (org.mconf.android.bbbandroid)  3.import (org.mconf.android.core)..previously it was showing 2 options i import(org.mconf.android.core) package its working .but now which package i have to import out of these 3

Comment: Without seeing your project setup then it's hard to say, it's definitely one of the org.mconf.android ones though.